# DetailView on custom user model on Django doesnt work

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have this link to 'My account' on my website

```
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user_detail' id=request.user.id %}">My Account</a>
      {% endif%}
```

on my **urls.py** i've this line

```
url(r'^users/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
   context_object_name = 'es_user'
   model = es_user
```

**models.py**

```
class es_user(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='es_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       print("self.user.id=",self.user.id)
       return reverse('user_detail', kwargs={'id': self.user.id })
```

But when I click on the '**My account**' link I get this error

```
AttributeError at /users/3

Generic detail view UserDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

Here 3 is the id of currently logged in user since the user is logged in `request.user.id` on this line `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user_detail' id=request.user.id %}">My Account</a>` is not returning any null values.

I cannot find the error using the error message given by django. somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

By default the URL pattern for `DetailView` looks for an ID field called `pk`.

You can either change your URL pattern to:
`url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),`

...or set the `pk_url_kwarg` on your class to be the following:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
   context_object_name = 'es_user'
   model = es_user
   pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked . but now I'm getting this error `No es_user found matching the query`

Answer (score 0):

From the django documentation:

Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

> The URLconf here uses the named group pk - this name is the default name that >DetailView uses to find the value of the primary key used to filter the queryset.
>
> If you want to call the group something else, you can set pk_url_kwarg on the >view. More details can be found in the reference for DetailView

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes and now everything works fine!

**`views.py`**

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'es_user'
    model = es_user
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

In the home page the link to '**My account**' was changed to

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user_detail' id=request.user.es_user.id %}">My Account</a>
{% endif%}
```

**models.py**

```
class es_user(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='es_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('user_detail', kwargs={'id': self.pk })
```